# Crystal Reports XI command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, .net-3.5, sql-server-2000

I am new to Crystal Reports and I wish to load Crystal Reports and refresh data

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgHGP.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWdy.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1E2Y.png)

using command line.

Basically I am trying to write a C# Windows Form Application to call the .bat files that calls Crystal Reports by passing parameters to fill in the window that I have attached for the snip shots.

I am told that this is very possible by my senior, but what I have learnt from hours of googling this isn't very possible unless I use a third party tool (mostly) or write my own application which I am being tasked to.

I'm open to other solutions too, because I need a list of solutions to propose to my senior who is persistent in thinking Crystal Reports itself has command line support without external tools or third library support.

Also, I do know that it is possible to install Crystal Reports Runtime support for Visual Studio 2008 (I am using this version), however, I am told that this is not possible because the whole process is done on a Windows Server 2003 PC and it is not possible to install anything there.

Anyways, why am I developing a C# Windows Form application to call the .bat files which passes parameters to Crystal Reports? 
It's because I am told that the Crystal Reports is not user friendly for non-programmers workers to generate report, by what I meant for generate report is to refresh the data like as shown in the images above and just print it.

Basically some additional features of the whole mess into developing a C# windows form application is to have a dropdown box with all store codes so the employees who aren't technical knows how to choose it without messing up anything (sounds 50/50 reasonable and unreasonable I know) or any other additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution to render a Crystal Report file to a PDF, while also stuffing in (default) parameters and setting login info from this commandline app:

https://github.com/gojimmypi/crMailer

Save PDF to file like this:

```
crReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, OutputFileWithPath);
```

Parameters assigned like this:

```
static void crAssignDefaultParameters()
{
    if (HasError)
    {
        VerboseWriteline("Skipping crAssignDefaultParameters after error was encountered.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (ParameterField item in crReportDocument.ParameterFields)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine("{0} In use? {1}", item.Name, crParameterInUse(item.Name));

        if (crParameterInUse(item.Name))
        {
            if (item.DefaultValues.Count == 0)
            {
                VerboseWriteline("Warning: no default value for " + item.Name + " assigned a value of empty string.");

                crReportDocument.SetParameterValue(item.Name, "");
            }
            else
            {
                VerboseWriteline("Assigned default value of " + item.DefaultValues[0] + " for " + item.Name + "." );
                crReportDocument.SetParameterValue(item.Name, ((CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue)item.DefaultValues[0]).Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            VerboseWriteline("Skipping " + item.Name + ", assuming this is a linked subreport parameter for " + item.ReportName + ".");

        }
    }
}
```